# Error during Boost Deserialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, segmentation-fault, deserialization

I am using Boost serialization for serializing Eigen MatrixXd and similarly trying to deserialize from the stored file using the method load_data as provided below. I see that although the file exits, c++ compiler always throws the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Please recommend.

```
#include "Serialize_data.h"
#include "CommonUtils.h"

struct RandomNode1 {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & random_feature_indices_;
    }
    MatrixXd random_feature_indices_;
};

namespace boost {
template<class Archive, typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options,
        int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar,
        Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> & t,
        const unsigned int file_version = 4209360273818925922L) {
    int rows = t.rows(), cols = t.cols();
    ar & rows;
    ar & cols;
    ar & boost::serialization::make_array(t.data(), rows * cols);
}
}

void save_data(MatrixXd vals) {
    // create and open a character archive for output
    ofstream ofs("filename.data");

    RandomNode1 r;
    r.random_feature_indices_ = vals;

    // save data to archive
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << r;
    }
    ofs.close();
}

void load_data(string path) {

    ifstream ifs(path);
    RandomNode1 r1;
    if (ifs.good()) {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> r1;
    } else {
        cerr << "Error loading file";
        assert(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you include ~5 more lines (includes + main) so that your example is self contained? Setting these up took more time than answering your question. Not everybody has so much time/interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selected a Matrix type with dynamic dimension

- [doc for MatrixXd](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga0750af9a6b82761985a15fe77256de87)

  ```
  typedef Matrix< double , Dynamic , Dynamic > MatrixXd
  ```

This means that if you restore from an archive, you have to actively make sure that you **restore** the dimensions too. This doesn't happen here:

```
int rows = t.rows(), cols = t.cols();
ar & rows;
ar & cols;
```

in fact, it initializes `rows` and `cols` with completely irrelevant default dimensions of the matrix **before** loading. And it ***fails to*** set the dimensions after reading `rows` and `cols` from the archive.

Unsurprisingly, the next step

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_array(t.data(), rows * cols);
```

won't succeed, unless the actual matrix type happens to have default dimensions sufficient to hold `rows * cols` elements.

Showing how to do things for at least `MatrixXd`:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    template<class Archive>
        inline void save(Archive & ar, MatrixXd const& t, unsigned int /*file_version*/) 
        {
            int rows = t.rows(), cols = t.cols();
            ar & rows;
            ar & cols;
            ar & boost::serialization::make_array(t.data(), rows * cols);
        }

    template<class Archive>
        inline void load(Archive & ar, MatrixXd & t, unsigned int /*file_version*/) 
        {
            int rows, cols;
            ar & rows;
            ar & cols;
            t = MatrixXd(rows, cols);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_array(t.data(), rows * cols);
        }

} }

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(MatrixXd)
```

This runs cleanly under valgrind.